# can you explain this different solution of exact differentiation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studied a lesson from Differential Equation that is Exact differentiation. I have moved on on this part and tackle euler's method but not completely, I'm still stuck with a question on exact differentation. I going to show you what I learn from the lesson reply if this wrong or  to my question

First example:

$ 2xy-9x^2+(2y+x^2+1)y'=0$

M is...

M=$2xy-9x^2$

and N is...

N=$2y+x^2+1$

so, we differiate M with Y and N with X.

so this is the answer.

$M_y= 2x$
$N_x= 2x$

so, there are same.

then, you may either integrate Mdx or Ndy:

I, first, $ \int M dx $

$ \int M dx $=$\int 2xy-9x^2 dx$
= $x^2y-3x^3+h(y)$

then we differentiate M by y

$x^2+h(y)'$

and compare to N to find $h(y)'$
N=$2y+x^2+1$

so, $h(y)'$ = $2y+1$ and integrate $\int x^2 + h(y)' dy$

you'll get $ y^2+y$

add $h(y) to M to make a solution

$ \psi(x,y)=x^2y-3x^3+y^2+y$ or

$y^2+(x^2+1)y-3x^3$

Now let's try $\int N dy$

$\int 2y+x^2+1 dy = \space y^2+x^2y+y+h(x)$

$N_x= 2xy+h(x)'$

$h(x)'=9x^2=\space \int h(x)'dx = \space 3x^3$

add $h(x)$ to integrated N and you have a solution

$\psi (x,y) = y^2+(x^2+1)y-3x^3$

I'm not telling you that how I learn the lesson but they are same solution whether you integrate M or N. I going to prove another example that they have also the same solution

Second Example: this one will be short because I show to you how to solve in the first example.

$2xy^2+4+(2x^2y-6)y'=0$

M=$2xy^2+4  \qquad M_y=4xy$

N=$2x^2y-6  \qquad N_x=4xy$

$\int M dx = X^2y^2+4x+h(y)$

$M_y= 2x^2y+h(y)' \qquad N= 2x^2y-6 \qquad h(y)'=-6 \qquad \int h(y)'=h(y)=6y$

solution: $\psi (x,y) = x^2y^2+4x-6y$

let's try N

$\int N dy = x^2y^2-6y+h(x)$

$N_x= 2xy^2+h(x)' \qquad M= 2xy^2+4 \qquad h(x)'=4 \qquad \int h(x)'=h(x)=4x$

solution: $\psi (x,y) = x^2y^2+4x-6y$

Now, I have proved to you no matter you integrated M or N, they are same solution. but the third example which I'm gonna show you the solution is different.

Third example:

$3y^3e^{3xy}-1+(2ye^{3xy}+3xy^2e^{3xy})y'=0$

M=$3y^3e^{3xy}-1          \qquad M_y= 9y^2e^{3xy}+9xy^3e^{3xy}$

N=$2ye^{3xy}+3xy^2e^{3xy} \qquad N_x= 9y^2e^{3xy}+9xy^3e^{3xy}$

Let's try M.

$\int M dx = y^2e^{3xy}-x+h(y)$

$M_y=2ye^{3xy}+3xy^2e^{3xy}+h(y)' \qquad N=2ye^{3xy}+3xy^2e^{3xy} \qquad h(y)'= 0$

so the solution is: $\psi (x,y) =y^2e^{3xy}-x$

then, Let's try N

$\int N dy = y^2e^{3xy}-\frac{2}{9x^2}e^{3xy}+h(x)$

those who are confuse, I'll give you the solution I used integration by parts.

first the first term

$2ye^{3xy}$

$u=2y \qquad v=\frac{1}{3x}e^{3xy}$

$du=2 \qquad dv=e^{3xy}$

=$\frac{2y}{3x}e^{3xy}-\frac{2}{9x^2}e^{3xy}$

now the second term

$3xy^2e^{3xy}$

$u=3xy^2 \qquad v=\frac{1}{3x}e^{3xy}$

$du=6xy \qquad dv=e^{3xy}$

=$y^2e^{3xy}-\frac{2y}{3x}e^{3xy}$

then, add them together

$\frac{2y}{3x}e^{3xy}-\frac{2}{9x^2}e^{3xy} + y^2e^{3xy}-\frac{2y}{3x}e^{3xy}$

cancel the two $\frac{2y}{3x}e^{3xy}$

then the $\int N dy = y^2e^{3xy}-\frac{2}{9x^2}e^{3xy}+h(x)$

now differentiate N to dx:

$N_x= 3y^3e^{3xy}- \frac{108y}{81x^3}+h(x)' \qquad $ $M= 3y^3e^{3xy}-1 /qquad $ $h(x)'=-1 /qquad \int h(x)' = h(x) =-x$

so the solution is :$\psi (x,y) =y^2e^{3xy}-\frac{2}{9x^2}e^{3xy}-x$

here is the solution when I integrate the Mdx:$\psi (x,y) = y^2e^{3xy}-x$

here is the solution when I integrate the Ndy:$\psi (x,y) =y^2e^{3xy}-\frac{2}{9x^2}e^{3xy}-x$

both M and N are exact, but the solution are different. Finally, my question to you: Is it correct or acceptable to have a different solution from integrating both M and N? or am I wrong in my calculation?

thanks.

Comment: You messed up your integration by parts after the phrase "now the second term".

Comment: $\int 3xy^2e^{3xy} dy = y^2e^{3xy}-\int {2y}e^{3xy} dx$  and now you have more integrating by parts to do...

Comment: I just write the final answer of integration. it's dy $\int 2ye^{3xy} dy$ not dx sorry I mistakenly write dx instead of dy